# Bake Cell fracture physics?

Tags: physics, baking, rigid-body-simulation

I have a vase that's broken with cell fracture and physics.

I only need it to stay broken, not be seen in motion.

is there a way to bake the broken pieces as they fell?

Thanks

Comment: Yes thanks, I did search for a solution but didn't find this